# SoftInput.AdjustPan doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, keyboard, window-soft-input-mode, soft-input-panel

Hello to all programmers. I try to create Android app in Visual Studio Xamarin. I placed EditText in the lower part of app screen and when I set focus on it, keyboard hide bottom part of UI. Is it possible to do something with this?

**Screens:**
[image: Keyboard hide]

**Code:**
[Main.axml](http://txt.do/dkgst)
[MainActivity.cs](http://txt.do/dkgs0)

All help will be appreciated

***UPDATED***

Theme code:

```
<resources>
  <style name="CustomToolbar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/status_bar</item>
  </style>
  <style name="TransparentStatusBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
  <style name="CustomSplash" parent ="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: post your TransparentStatusBar theme code plz. some style item is ignore SoftInput.AdjustPan. (ex. <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item> )

Comment: To @배준모 Yes, you are right, I use windowTranslucentNavigation. I added code of theme

Comment: if use windowTranslucentNavigation, SoftInput.AdjustPan not working..i dont know why...so remove it

Comment: i think maybe  windowTranslucentNavigation is layout fixed. so maybe...not resizing layout

Comment: To @배준모 Well, thank you for help with dependencies between AdjustPan/Resize and windowTranslucentNavigation. Will think how to fix this my own way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your layout inside **ScrollView**. I will allow EditText to be fully visible, but it will not do anything with bottom buttons since they do not block that field.

If you want to make it more pressure for eyes, you can scroll ScrollView when the keyboard is presented on the screen.

EDIT:
To find out when the keyboard appears, you can use **GlobalLayout** event of the main layout.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = element.ViewTreeObserver;       
vto.GlobalLayout += (sender, args) => {      
        element.Height; // will be different with/without keyboard 
};
```

Comment: Can you explain, how to control presenting keyboard on the screen, please?

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus I edited the answer for your request

Comment: To @Taier. Ok, but how I can get this element (keyboard). That the first. Second - with windowTranslucentNavigation AdjustPan or AdjustResize don't work, so ScrollView will not help  Whithout windowTranslucentNavigation both works.